# How to convert String object to IntWritable Object in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to convert `String` object to `IntWritable` Object in Hadoop.
any process is available for conversion.

Answer (score 12):

```
IntWritable value = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(someString))
```

... and deal with the possibility that `parseInt` may throw a `NumberFormatException`.

---

Someone asked:

> How to overcome this NumberFormatException ???

The exception will occur if `someString` does not represent an integer.

What do you do?

You catch it and handle it of course!  How you handle it (i.e. what you should code your application to do) will depending on the context.  We can't advise on that.

Java exceptions and exception handling are described in the Oracle Java Tutorials - [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).