# Hadoop - IntWritable(int) constructor not loaded

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to make a MapReduce in Hadoop, and want to convert a String to an IntWritable for it. I'm following the advice listed here: [How to convert String object to IntWritable Object in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425949/how-to-convert-string-object-to-intwritable-object-in-hadoop/).
It advises to use

```
new IntWriteable(Integer.parseInt(someString))
```

so what I am trying is

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable > {
private final Text wordKey = new Text("");

public void map(LongWritable ikey, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] friend = value.toString().split(";");
    String[] friendswith = friend[1].split(",");
    for (String s : friendswith) {
        wordKey.set(friend[0]);
        context.write(wordKey, IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(s))); //trying to convert here
      }
   }
}
```

but get the error

```
The method IntWritable(int) is undefined for the type MyMapper
```

According to the documentation [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html#IntWritable(int)/) it notes, that there is a contructor that accepts an `int` as an input. I do have `IntWritable` imported:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
```

What might cause that I cannot use the `IntWritable(int)` constructor?

Comment: You are missing `new` keyword between `context.write(wordKey` and `IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(s)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yout are missing the `new` keyword.

In the line

```
context.write(wordKey, IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(s)));
```

you are not creating an instance of `IntWritable`, instead you are trying to call a method named `IntWritable` which is not defined.

Try this:

```
context.write(wordKey, new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(s)));
```

Comment: Oh. Right. Thank you! :)